# SQL Group By with calculator task

Tags: sql

I want to calculate the percent of the fee with group by with city and country

```
City       Country   Percent
New York   US        ?
```

I have a table that looks like this:

| ID | Name | City | Country | Fee |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Mike | NY | USA | 1000$ |
| 1 | Kaia | DL | USA | 2000$ |
| 1 | Lee | HCM | VN | 3000$ |
| 1 | Yuna | PK | VN | 4000$ |

I want to get the percent of fee from customers in NY in comparison to anyone in the USA.

Like here 1000$ from NY/1000$+2000$ from USA.

How should I go about querying this?

Comment: Take the [tour], read [ask], and post a [mcve].

Comment: What rdbms are you using? MySQL, sql server, oracle etc?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution coded on SQL server. It will run on most RDBMS.

> ```
> create table fees(
> ID int,
> Name varchar(10),
> City varchar(10),
> Country varchar(10),
> Fee int);
> insert into fees values
> (1,'Mike','NY','USA',1000),
> (1,'Kaia','DL','USA',2000),
> (1,'Lee','HCM','VN',3000),
> (1,'Yuna','PK','VN',4000);
> ```

> ```
> SELECT
>   ID,
>   Name,
>   City,
>   f.Country,
>   Fee,
>   100*Fee/sf  pourcent_country
> FROM fees f
> LEFT JOIN (SELECT country, SUM(fee) sf FROM fees GROUP BY country) c
> ON f.country = c.country
> ORDER BY Country, City
> ```
>
> ```
> ID | Name | City | Country |  Fee | pourcent_country
> -: | :--- | :--- | :------ | ---: | ---------------:
>  1 | Kaia | DL   | USA     | 2000 |               66
>  1 | Mike | NY   | USA     | 1000 |               33
>  1 | Lee  | HCM  | VN      | 3000 |               42
>  1 | Yuna | PK   | VN      | 4000 |               57
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a369dd7a13d450576174182762a26f02)*